# Wrong item is getting selected in AutoCompleteTextView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I am facing an issue in `AutoCompleteTextView` adapter. I have to create autocomplete adapter which will display the filtered contact list from the device. In my case, the filtering is working fine. But **when I select an item from the list, the data set in the `AutoCompleteTextView` is from the original list, not from the filtered list.** Can any one help me to resolve the issue?

Please find my adapter class below

```
class ContactListAdapter(private var ctx: Context, private var contacts: ArrayList<MobileContact>):
    ArrayAdapter<MobileContact>(ctx, R.layout.contact_item, contacts) {

    private var filter: ContactFilter? = null

    private class ViewHolder(view: View?) {
        var name: TextView? = null
        var number: TextView? = null

        init {
            name = view?.findViewById(R.id.contactName)
            number = view?.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber)
        }
    }

    private val filteredContacts = ArrayList<MobileContact>()

    override fun getCount() = filteredContacts.size

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return if(filter == null)
            ContactFilter(this, contacts)
        else filter!!
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        val contact = filteredContacts[position]

        val inflater = ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            view = convertView
            viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        viewHolder.name?.text = contact.name
        viewHolder.number?.text = contact.number

        return view
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    class ContactFilter(private var adapter: ContactListAdapter, private var contacts: ArrayList<MobileContact>) : Filter() {
        private var filteredContacts = ArrayList<MobileContact>()

        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            filteredContacts.clear()
            val results = FilterResults()
            if(constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredContacts.addAll(contacts)
            } else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).trim()
                for(contact in contacts) {
                    if(contact.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains(filterPattern) ||
                            contact.number.contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredContacts.add(contact)
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredContacts
            results.count = filteredContacts.size
            return results
        }

        override fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any?): CharSequence {
            return (resultValue as MobileContact).number
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            adapter.filteredContacts.clear()
            adapter.filteredContacts.addAll(results?.values as ArrayList<MobileContact>)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I resolved the issue. Here what I did is I removed the filtered results from the adapter. And the filter will be kept the whole data.

Please find the code below. Someone may have useful

```
class ContactListAdapter(private var ctx: Context, private var contacts: ArrayList<MobileContact>):
    ArrayAdapter<MobileContact>(ctx, R.layout.contact_item, contacts) {

    private var filter = ContactFilter()

    private class ViewHolder(view: View?) {
        var name: TextView? = null
        var number: TextView? = null

        init {
            name = view?.findViewById(R.id.contactName)
            number = view?.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber)
        }
    }

    override fun getCount() = contacts.size

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return filter
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        val contact = contacts[position]

        val inflater = ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            view = convertView
            viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        viewHolder.name?.text = contact.name
        viewHolder.number?.text = contact.number

        return view
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    inner class ContactFilter : Filter() {
        private var filteredContacts = ArrayList<MobileContact>()
        private var origList = ArrayList<MobileContact>()

        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            if(origList.isEmpty())
                origList.addAll(contacts)

            filteredContacts.clear()
            val results = FilterResults()
            if(constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredContacts.addAll(origList)
            } else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).trim()
                for(contact in origList) {
                    if(contact.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains(filterPattern) ||
                            contact.number.contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredContacts.add(contact)
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredContacts
            results.count = filteredContacts.size
            return results
        }

        override fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any?): CharSequence {
            return (resultValue as MobileContact).number
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            contacts.clear()
            contacts.addAll(results?.values as ArrayList<MobileContact>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```